# How can i get a variable that was definied in class and use the it somewhere else

Tags: php, class, codeigniter

i am using codeignighter.

I have a class that has some variables i need to use somewhere else.

for example:

```
 class details{

public $username;
public $current_uID;
public $member_status;

    public function __construct(){
         $this->username = 'username';
         $this->current_uID = 21;
         $this->member_status = 1;
    }
}
```

Now my question is how do i access the those variable - and if i do will they have the values that was defined in the construct ?

Comment: this has more to do with php classes than codeigniter right?  Just create an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$details = new details();

$username = $details->username;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create the class and use the properties of the created instance:

```
$details = new details();
echo $details->username;  // will put 'username' on the screen
```